# Concurrency settings for Spring Cloud Stream Pubsub using executor-threads and parallel-pull-count

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.executor-threads
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.subscriber.parallel-pull-count
```

I understand that the concurrency = executor-threads * parallel-pull-count. What I'm asking is how different combination of them will be better than the other.
Suppose I need to have concurrency of 6, each message can be processed in around 5 seconds. Which combination will be best?

```
parallel-pull-count = 1 and executor-threads = 6 OR
parallel-pull-count = 6 and executor-threads = 1 OR
parallel-pull-count = 2 and executor-threads = 3 OR
parallel-pull-count = 3 and executor-threads = 2
```